# Spring Boot and Jetty's ProxyServlet

Tags: spring-boot

WHat I have looks like that:

```
@RestController
public class JsonRPCProxy extends ProxyServlet
```

Proxy servlet is a part of org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.
In PostCOnstruct I'm trying to init super, however it fails on NPE of httpClient of the ProxyServlet. My Spring app does not have a web.xml. So, the question is how to init ProxyServlet anyway?
Thanks in advance,
Oleg

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done in implementation of Jetty. ProxyServlet should be @Component/@Bean.
What I did actually, took async template and removed ProxyServlet.